# Check if datetime happened in the last 7 minutes

Tags: php, php-carbon

I am using `PHP 7.4.1` and `Laravel Framework 6.20.12` with the `carbon` library.

I want to check if a date has happened 7 minutes in the past.

I tried:

```
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $lastPosting = $now->addMinutes(7);



        if($now->gt($lastPosting)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

The problem with the above code is that it sets all dates that are in the past to true.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Are you sure it's returning TRUE, not FALSE? Because it's pretty clear that `$now` is the current time, and `$lastPosting` is 7 minutes from now, so `$now->gt($lastPosting)` should always evaluate to FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with Carbon but here's my approach: use `between()`:

```php
if($lastPosting->between( $now->subMinutes(7), $now){
    //anything in between the last 7 minutes
}
else{
    //whatever else
}
```